# is there a recommended way of feeding logstash with azure operation logs?

Tags: azure, logstash

I need to collect Azure operation logs to feed my ELK (elasticsearch, logstash and kibaba) cluster.

I'm looking for a ready-to-use solution. If none is available, I can write my own and in this case I'm looking for a design which is simple and reliable.

My current design is to have a worker role which uses Azure's REST API to fetch logs every minute or so and push log entries to my ELK cluster. Sounds like that will cost U$20/no and I'll have to design some bookkeeping for the periods which my worker role is interrupted.

With so many input options, my hope was that logstash had a plugin for this task.